# input field not populating from dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, dom, autocomplete, algolia

I have a script attached to an input field. It's an address autocomplete service Algolia places). I have the script working: suggestions start showing up as you type in, and once a suggestion is selected it shows as if it populated the field. however when the form is submitted it only shows the letters that were typed in manually and not the selected suggestion.
Anyway to fix this?

```js
(function() {
  var placesAutocomplete = places({
    appId: 'APPID',
    apiKey: 'APIKEY',
    container: document.querySelector('input[name="address-line1"]'),
    templates: {
      value: function(suggestion) {
        return suggestion.name;
      }
    }
  }).configure({
    type: 'address'
  });
  placesAutocomplete.on('change', function resultSelected(e) {
    document.querySelector('#ec-city-list').value = e.suggestion.city || '';
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/places.js@1.19.0"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry, @mplungjanbut unfortunately I'm a beginner and I don't know how to make it to a minimal reproducible example. However to address your error you need to change the container to an input field you want to add the script to. [link](https://community.algolia.com/places/documentation.html) here is the documetion where the script is explaind.

Comment: I see one needs a key, so never mind

Comment: DO you submit document.querySelector('#ec-city-list').value?

Comment: So the script offers address suggestions that are being typed in input[name="address-line1"], once a suggestion is selected it populates that input field with the street name and the (#'ec-city-list') with the suggestion's city attribute. It's a google maps like sevice.